# How to correctly setup Logback in an Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, slf4j, logback

I have spent the last 2 or 3 days trying to get Logback correctly working in my new Eclipse RCP Project. (I'm trying RCP for the first time, but have used logback in other java projects).

My questions to all of you out there are: "Is there a simple plugin for Eclipse RCP (E4) to enable Logback logging? Should the plugin here (http://logback.qos.ch/p2/) be used?  If there isn't a simple plugin to use, what is the correct way to enable this logging?"

I've read this page (http://devblog.virtage.com/2012/07/logback-and-eclipse-attaching-logback-xml/) many times and it seems promising, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: If this is just for logging errors in an e4 RCP you should use `org.eclipse.e4.core.services.statusreporter.StatusReporter`

Comment: Can you give me a good example of using StatusReporter?  My searches haven't given a good/clear example.

Comment: `IStatus status = statusReporter.newStatus(IStatus.ERROR, "message", any exception);
  statusReporter.report(status, StatusReporter.LOG);`

Comment: Logback needs to find it's configuration file. Try with `-Dlogback.statusListenerClass=ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener`

Answer (score 5):

I've managed to get a working configuration for logback, that works with RCP 3.x and 4.x. I am building with Tycho, and use features and products to assemble the apps (see the [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) for details). The steps are:

1. In your defining plugin (usually the one containing your application), add dependencies to ch.qos.logback.classic and ch.qos.logback.core, as well as org.slf4j.api. All other plugins just need to depend on org.slf4j.api to access loggers.
2. In the feature that includes your defining plugin, add the ch.qos.logback.slf4j fragment on the Included PLug-ins page. Without this, SLF4J won't be able to find Logback in the deployed product.
3. Create a logback.xml file in your defining plugin somewhere in classpath (src/main/resources if you are using Tycho/Maven).
4. For an e4 application, add a life cycle manager, and initialize Logback in its @ProcessAdditions method:

   ```
   ILoggerFactory iLoggerFactory = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();  
   LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) iLoggerFactory;  
   loggerContext.reset();  
   JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();  
   configurator.setContext(loggerContext);  
   try {  
     configurator.doConfigure(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/logback.xml"));  
   } catch (JoranException e) {  
     throw new IOException(e.getMessage(), e);  
   }
   ```
5. For an Eclipse 3.x, application, the above code goes into the `start()` method of your application plugin's Activator.

You will probably want to use a file appender, as standard out is not shown unless you use -consoleLog as a program argument. If you specify the file location as `<file>${user.dir}/path/to/file</file>`, the file will be created in the application install directory. Generally you would use the workspace metadata directory, so that it is alongside the Eclipse log, e.g. `<file>${user.dir}/workspace/.metadata/rcp.log</file>`.

Comment: I tried this. It works in running within IDE but when I build RCP product it doesn't work. It finds the logback.xml so it configures but logback doesn't emit any log files. Any idea what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple.
Put your logback.xml file in directory /config (or wherever you want inside your plugin)
In your plugin project (plugin.xml), do the following.

- dependencies tab: add : org.slf4j.api,ch.qos.logback.classic ch.qos.logback.core
- build tab, "binary build", check the file "config/logback.xml"

In your intialisation class (class pointed by "lifeCycleURI" in plugin.xml) add the following:

```
@PostContextCreate
public void init()
   ...
   SLF4JConfigurator.configure();
   ...
}
```

The SLF4JConfigurator  class:

```
public final class SLF4JConfigurator {

private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(SLF4JConfigurator.class).getSymbolicName();
private static final String LOGBACK_XML = "platform:/plugin/" + BUNDLE_NAME + "/config/logback.xml";

public static void configure() {

  // Reset Current SLF4J config
  JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
  LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
  configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
  loggerContext.reset();

  // Read Configuration file
  try {
     URL configFile = new URL(LOGBACK_XML);
     InputStream configurationStream = configFile.openStream();
     configurator.doConfigure(configurationStream);
     configurationStream.close();
  } catch (JoranException | IOException e) {
     // Problem when reading file...
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  StatusPrinter.printInCaseOfErrorsOrWarnings(loggerContext);

  // Confirm message
  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SLF4JConfigurator.class);
  logger.info("Logging configuration initialised.");
}
}
```

Include the 3 dependencies in your "product" defintion. If you build with tycho, the slf4j+logback plugins plugins from eclipse will be automatically bundled with your app, nothing specific to add to your pom files.
This is how I do it in  [JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox/?source=navbar)  (On sourceforge)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt of my working `pom.xml` of a plugin of an RCP app:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>es.fcc.rds</groupId>
  <artifactId>fcc.ima.oda</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
  <properties>
    <tycho.version>0.19.0</tycho.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>eclipse</id>
      <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler</url>
      <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>logback</id>
      <url>http://logback.qos.ch/p2/</url>
      <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ....
```

As you can see, I'm using the `http://logback.qos.ch/p2/` repository.

**Note**: after many months of working ok, it now fails intermitently, maybe due to problems of the p2 repository.